# unattended-upgrades.service using an outdated library in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, services, libraries, unattended-upgrades

Whenever I execute an *apt-get upgrade*, I am confronted with a popup telling me that two of my daemons are using outdated libraries, and I am asked whether or not I wish to restart those services.

One is **unattended-upgrades.service**, another is the **networkd-dispatcher.service**. Both services run after a reboot of the server, but are not restarted after an *apt-get upgrade* unless I manually select them in the interactive popup.

Is there a way to identify and update the libraries that are triggering the popup? Should it be concerning that outdated libraries are being used for these services?

I am NOT interested in preventing this popup from occurring when outdated libraries are detected, as was addressed in the question [apt-get upgrade auto restart services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139). I value the feedback. I'm asking to learn if there is a way to update the outdated libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get upgrade auto restart services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services)

Comment: Not really. I saw this before posting. I'm not objecting to the existence of the popup. I'm concerned about what it is telling me: that there are outdated libraries being used. I wish to know more about setting my system up so it doesn't make use of outdated libraries, if possible.

Comment: Unattended Upgrades service should not be active all the time: It's triggered by a pair of systemd timers, runs, and then terminates until next time. I suspect you have encountered a bug -- please report it.

Comment: @user535733 What is the bug? I'm thinking the service should be running when the server (it's a remote server) is first rebooted. And if it hasn't yet terminated as you say it should when I execute apt-get upgrade, it should probably be restarted, yes? Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner What it tells you is that some libraries had been recently updated, but services that depend on them still expect the old versions, and should be restarted to make them aware of new versions. Auto-restart of services should solve it.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you for the input. If I manually restart the services (that depend on old versions) in response to the popup, should that also make them aware the new versions? It seems for now a second `apt-get upgrade` does not trigger the popup (nor does it upgrade anything). But I've had these same two services being brought to my attention a number of times. I guess I'll just have to wait to see if they pop up again.