# How do I skip the interactive prompts asking to restart services on apt upgrade?

Tags: apt

When doing an `apt update -y && apt upgrade -y` for an automated script (that runs on startup in an interactive shell) I am prompted to restart certain services.

[image]

My script looks like

```bash
#!bin/bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export NEEDRESTART_MODE=a

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y --fix-broken install
```

This is a "remote dev environment" based on Ubuntu that can only be accessed via ssh and is wiped when restarted - so I run these commands on initial ssh login (in an interactive shell).

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; what do you mean by *base on Ubuntu* specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get upgrade auto restart services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services)