# bash install without restart popups

Tags: bash, 22.04, services

Bash script at bottom, on Ubuntu 22.04. It keeps getting popups to restart services on install, you can see I have tried quite a few approaches.

```
sudo apt update -y
```

and

```
sudo apt install -y libgl1
```

seem to be the problem scripts. And here us an image:

[image: reboot request]

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a policy-rc.d script to prevent services from being automatically started/restarted
echo '#!/bin/sh' | sudo tee /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d > /dev/null
echo 'exit 101' | sudo tee -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d > /dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

# Set environment variables to make apt non-interactive
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true

echo "Updating the package list..."
sudo apt update -y

echo "Installing python3-pip..."
sudo apt install -y python3-pip

echo "Installing libgl1..."
sudo apt install -y libgl1

# Remove the policy-rc.d script to allow services to be started/restarted again
sudo rm /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

echo "Restarting services using outdated libraries..."
sudo needrestart -r a
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get upgrade auto restart services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services)