# How to answer "Which services should be restarted?" after running `apt dist-upgrade` in console?

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, 22.04, systemd

After running `apt dist-upgrade` in a root shell in Ubuntu Server 22.04.3, sometimes the question `Which services should be restarted?` is shown. Example:

```
Restarting services...
Daemons using outdated libraries
--------------------------------

  1. dbus.service  2. getty@tty1.service  3. multipathd.service  4. networkd-dispatcher.service  5. packagekit.service  6. polkit.service  7. ssh.service  8. systemd-logind.service  9. systemd-manager  10. thermald.service  11. unattended-upgrades.service  12. user@1000.service  13. none of the above

(Enter the items or ranges you want to select, separated by spaces.)

Which services should be restarted? 1-13

Which services should be restarted? 1 - 13

Which services should be restarted? 1..13

Which services should be restarted? 1 .. 13

Which services should be restarted? 1...13

Which services should be restarted? 1 ... 13

Which services should be restarted? 1 to 13

Which services should be restarted? 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

Which services should be restarted? 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

Which services should be restarted?
```

The only answer I got working in this prompt was to input a single number, which would only restart that one service and then exit. Example:

```
Which services should be restarted? 1

 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
Service restarts being deferred:
 systemctl restart getty@tty1.service
 systemctl restart multipathd.service
 systemctl restart networkd-dispatcher.service
 systemctl restart packagekit.service
 systemctl restart polkit.service
 systemctl restart ssh.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/systemd-manager
 systemctl restart thermald.service
 systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service
 systemctl restart user@1000.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
root@ubuntu-server:~#
```

How do I answer this prompt to restart all (or a selection of multiple) services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you realize that option 13 is `none of the above`? Meaning, it should not be included if you wanted to restart any of the other items?

So just respond with omitting option 13:

```
Which services should be restarted? 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

or since ranges are also accepted:

```
Which services should be restarted? 1-12
```

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Thx for the edit. It looks a lot better now. Lesson learned.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: Is there a way to automatically tell it to do this, without keyboard input?

Comment: Please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services) and its answers.